# PyVista: how to contour on vertical slices?

Tags: slice, contour, pyvista

PyVista has with `slices` a nice feature to explore a mesh.

[image: PyVista slice]

**My question**: Is there a way to generate countours on such a slice (let's say in the xz-plane) ?

**What works** fine are contours in the xy-plane logic.

**What I want to achive**: I generate 3-dimensional curved grids over complex topography. So, the Matterhorn will be the lower boundary at iz=0, whereas the grid will be used for airflow modelling over and around the Matterhorn (not shown here). The slice capabilities of PyVista would be a wonderful tool to analyze the results.

[image]

Comment: Are you aware of the `contour=True` option in `slice()`? Does that not do what you're looking for?

Comment: @ Andreas Deak: Thanks, that was helpful! (no I wasn't aware of). My questions: (1) where can I find all parameters for the `slice()` commands?, (2) is it possible to draw both in the same plot (a) the colored canvas with  `contour=False` AND (b) the contours with `contour=True`

Comment: (1) [in the documentation](https://docs.pyvista.org/version/stable/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.DataSetFilters.slice.html) or interactively with `help(mesh.slice)`. (2) All `contour=True` does is give you `mesh.slice(..., contour=False).contour()`. So you can do `mesh_slice = mesh.slice(..., contour=False)`, then `contours = mesh_slice.contour()`, and then do as you please with these two filtered datasets (e.g. add them to the same `Plotter`).